# Read and print only positive array indexes

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, negative-number

The question i have is similar to some questions answered, but the answer for this in particular wasn't in there. Here is my code

```
    int main()
{   int i,j,k,sorted;
    int A[4][4];
    int C[16];
    int positive = 0;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<4; j++)
        {
            printf("A[%d][%d]: ", i,j);
            scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);

            if(A[i][j]>0){
                C[positive] = A[i][j];
                printf("C = %d\n");         
                positive++;
            }       
        }
    }
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        printf("%d  ", A[positive]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //printf("Your positive numbers are: ", positive);

    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

I want to check if the input is negative and add it to the 1D array only then. The question is how do I do that?

Comment: Start by cranking up your warning levels and *not* ignoring them. That `printf` format specifier requesting an `int` and being given an `int*` spells trouble. You also go through a lot of work to save off *values* from `A` in `C`, then never do anything with them. Also, `positive` an easily exceed `4` (the stated superior dimension of `A`, yet you use `positive` as an index into `A`. You need to rethink your entire algorithm as well as what actual *data* you're supposed to be saving and reporting (and from where). From what I can see, there is no need for`A` in this code *at all*.

Comment: Also there is an argument missing from `printf("C = %d\n");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**General Tips**

```
int main()
{   

int i,j,k,sorted; // do not declare loop control variables outside of their respective loops
int A[4][4];
int C[16];
int positive = 0; // for readability's sake please refrain from using long ass variable names for simple control var's

for(i=0;i<4;i++) // idiomatic way is for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j<4; j++) // for(int j = 0; j<4; j++)
    {
        printf("A[%d][%d]: ", i,j);
        scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);

        if(A[i][j]>0)
        {
            C[positive] = A[i][j];
            printf("C = %d\n"); // missing argument & redundant since you intend to print them afterwards anyway? 
            positive++;
        }       
    }
}
for(j=0;j<4;j++) // this loop is supposed to print all positive numbers?
{
    printf("%d  ", A[positive]); // you are looping through A[0-3][0], which are not necessarily the positive numbers of A.
}
printf("\n");
//printf("Your positive numbers are: ", positive);
```

Now to your question at hand. What the code tries to do and what you ask from us are two different things. Right now you are adding positive values to your C array, but your question asks about negative values?

**Cleaned up code that behaves the way i think you want it to.**

```
int main()
{
int A[4][4];
int C[16];
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        printf("A[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
        scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
        if (A[i][j] > 0) 
        {
            C[k] = A[i][j];
            k++;
        }
    }
}
printf("positive numbers in matrix A are: ");
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) // loop from 0 to actual number of positive integers; array size remains at 16 in this case.
{
    printf("%d  ", C[i]);
}
printf("\n");
//printf("Your positive numbers are: ", positive);
printf("\n");
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: My idea was to get rid of all negative numbers and store them under "positive". I am happy that you solved it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{   int i,j,k,sorted;
int A[4][4];
int C[16];
int positive = 0;

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j<4; j++)
    {
        printf("A[%d][%d]: ", i,j);
        scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);

        if(A[i][j]>0){
            C[positive] = A[i][j];
            printf("C = %d\n");         
            positive++;
        }       
    }
}
for(j=0;j<positive;j++)
{
    printf("%d  ", C[j]);
}
printf("\n");
//printf("Your positive numbers are: ", positive);

printf("\n");
system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

where you wrong is in the looping for result, you print a 2D array but you just use 1D array, and in the loop is not until 4 but until the positive, and then in the loop, you print A, but the result is C no A

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I checked it again and found out where i had mistakes.